# How to check the diff in two instances in same model in django

Tags: python, django, diff, checksum

Suppose I program a "Job" to process the input and give an output. It produces many different objects and be stored in different database tables (12~20 models)

**I need to diff two jobs output, users may have some modified in the input and leads to the output change.**

I need to find out which instances are changed in the models.

I tried to add the compare() method to each model and use the name to index the instance in two Jobs. (Found=>Compare)

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   job_id = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
   content1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   content2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   content2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)

   def compare(self, comp)
      excluded = "id", "job_id"
      d1, d2 = self.__dict__, comp.__dict__
      for k, v in d1.items():
          if k in excluded:
             continue
          if v != d2[k]:
              return False
      return True
```

Most of the models which have a mutual name index may work, I can use the name to find the mutual instance in two jobs and then call the compare() to test the difference.

However, in some models, the name is not a very proper way to index two instances since the name is more like an order. So the instance name may shift if new instances are added in the job process.

example.

```
job1: [ins1, ins2, ins3]
job2: [ins1, newIns2, ins2, ins3]
```

=> Both ins2's content are the same but the name has changed because n2 is added.

I have to list the newIns2, ins2, and ins3.

Then I come up with to compute every instance's checksum according to cotent1, content2, and content3.

Create two `{checksum: object}` dictionaries to test integrity.

Is checksum a good solution for my scenario?

If yes, do I need to create a field of checksum to store for each model?

How can I exclude the key to calculate the checksum? (pk, job_id, or name in some models.)